# Accessing an instantiated object created with a constructor in another class

Tags: c#, class

I have a code skeleton that shows two classes below. It's a simple instantiation stored into the instance variable called `_valueList`.

```
public class EvenBetterValueList : GH_Component
{
    ValueList _valueList;

    protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
    {
        // firstList and secondList declarations
        _valueList = new ValueList(firstList, secondList);
    }
}

public class EvenBetterValueListCustomAttributes : GH_ComponentAttributes
{
    // Access the instantiated _valueList from above in this class
}
```

**I am interested in accessing this instance**, its name `_valueList`, **in my second class**. I have some `setters` and `getters` in which it would retrieve strings, etc.

Some things I have currently tried is `private EvenBetterValueList newOne;`

And trying `newOne.someGetter`, with some setters and getters declared in my first class, but understandably, `newOne` is `null` because it's never instantiated which I don't want to do, because that means I'm creating a new instance versus accessing `_valueList` in my first class.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, might what you're looking for be a public, static variable or property? In which case, you could do something like EvenBetterValueList.ValueList and obviously in its getter provide whatever you need... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: Is the second class `EvenBetterValueListCustomAttributes` or is it a class that you haven't included (in which case, why the attributes?).  If you want to expose ValueList, declare a `public ValueList { get; private set; }` in `EvenBetterValueList` and then your second class will be able to access that property.

Comment: Hey guys. I am working on a Grasshopper 3D component. The Attributes is simply a new class that allows you to change the way the component looks on the Grasshopper canvas.

Comment: @48klocs Could you elaborate? Do you mean under my `ValueList _valueList` instance declaration, also add `public ValueList VList { get { return _valueList; } }`? How do you access this under my second class? If you don't mind, I think you're onto the right answer. Could you please put it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to instantiate that object? You could set up a property as follows: `public static ValueList TheList { get... }` and then access it like `EvenBetterValueList.TheList` but you understand the implications of static, I hope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an instantiated variable from another class, it will either need to be marked as public, or exposed via a public property exactly as described in the answer that @48klocs provided (a property is preferred).

In this case, the containing class needs to be instantiated if we're talking about accessing instance-level variables (which exist within the scope of the instantiated class).

Or, in the case of the example in your question, you'd have an instantiated object of type `EvenBetterValueList` and at some point, the method `SolveInstance` is called which will initialize `_valueList`. I notice that method is protected and overridden, so presumably something is happening to make that call. Then, if you have a public property exposing that variable, you can call it via the instance of `EvenBetterValueList`.

The disconnect seems to be that you want to access an instance-level variable as if it's class-level (static).

Here is some code to hopefully better visualize my answer (this assumes you have a public property written that exposes `_valueList`):

```
EvenBetterValueList myEvenBetterValueList = new EvenBetterValueList(); // your instance of EvenBetterValueList

...
// some work happens so that within the scope of myEvenBetterValueList, SolveInstance is called, 
// which initializes _valueList

// now we can get that object
ValueList theValueList = myEvenBetterValueList.ValueList;
```

Comment: Hey Manny. Interested issue I'm experiencing right now. My project involves two classes, and when I use this code, one or more instances will be created (from those two classes). Thus, it seems, the `static` scope (global scope) means that one change in one instance affects all other instances. `private static string _title = "Value List"; ` and `public static string Title{get { return _title;}}`. That's how I am using it. Is there any way to have it global only in the two classes and not beyond that?

Comment: I think this is what you meant by the implications of global variables, and I am running into it right now.

Comment: Yep, you don't want to use `static` in this case.  `_valueList` should be an instance member, so no `static` modifier on the declaration. So you should be dealing with instances of `EvenBetterValueList` as demonstrated in this answer. Some further reading on static vs instance fields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645751(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Access to a class's instance variables is normally mediated through properties - they form the contract of what a class provides to the outside world and allow it to mediate how much control consumers have over their internals.

```
public class EvenBetterValueList : GH_Component
{
    ValueList _valueList;
    public ValueList ValueList
    {
        get { return _valueList; }
    }
}
```

Once you've exposed `ValueList` as a property, then `EvenBetterValueListCustomAttributes` will be able to access the value of `EvenBetterValueList.ValueList` from the instance of `EvenBetterValueList` that it contains.

Comment: I did what you posted but declaring a getter. But it seems I am unable to call `EvenBetterValueList.ValueList` in my `EvenBetterValueListCustomAttributes` class :/.

Comment: I address this in my comments under your question. It sounds like you're looking for a static property but remember that a static variable is, for lack of a better word, global to the scope of your program.

Comment: Wow Manny.. I apologize again for not following your advice. You were right ALL ALONG. The `static` was all I needed. It made no sense to me, but you're right that `static` means it becomes global scope. Wow. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, @theGreenCabbage. I did just post an answer with more detail, but be aware of the implications of `static`.  I'm don't have the context to this solution, but I just feel I should emphasize that point. Good luck!

Comment: To make it a bit less of a riddle, `static` classes exist once per application domain.  If the intent is to have a singleton-ish object, it's one way to achieve it.

Comment: @48klocs Love your display picture by the way.